# Drawing Text with Core Graphics

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, core-text

I need to draw centered text to a CGContext.

I started with a Cocoa approach. I created a NSCell with the text and tried to draw it thus:

```
NSGraphicsContext* newCtx = [NSGraphicsContext
     graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:bitmapContext flipped:true];
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:newCtx];
[pCell setFont:font];
[pCell drawWithFrame:rect inView:nil];
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
```

But the CGBitmapContext doesn't seem to have the text rendered on it. Possibly because I have to pass nil for the inView: parameter.

So I tried switching text rendering to Core Graphics:

The simplest way seems to be to use CGContextSelectFont to select a font using its postscript name, and point size, but CGContextShowTextAtPoint only takes non-unicode characters, and there is no apparent way to fit the text to a rectangle: or to compute the extents of a line of text to manually lay out the rectangle.

Then, there is a CGFont that can be created, and set cia CGContextSetFont. Drawing this text requires CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint, but again the CGContext seems to be lacking functions to compute the bounding rect of generated text, or to wrap the text to a rect. Plus  how to transform a string to an array of CGGlyphs is not obvious.

The next option is to try using CoreText to render the string. But the Core Text classes are hugely complicated, and while there are samples that show how to display text, in a specified font, in a rect, there are no samples demonstrating how to compute the bounding rect of a CoreText string.

So:

- Given a CGFont a CGContext how do I compute the bounding rect of some text, and how do I transform a text string into an array of CGGlyphs?
- Given a string, a CGContext and a postscript name and point size, what Core Text objects do I need to create to compute the bounding rect of the string, and/or draw the string wrapped to a rect on the CGContext.
- Given a string and a NSFont - how do I render the string onto a CGBitmapContext? I already know how to get its extents.

Comment: could you draw an example of desired result?

Comment: perhaps, but the desired result is reslly simple - I want to draw a string, with a font (face and point size) in a rect. The string must be wrapped, and I must be able to choose if the lines are left, middle, or right aligned, and also the paragraph to be top, center, or bottom aligned.

Answer (score 9):

I finally managed to find answers after 4 days of searching. I really wish Apple makes better documentation. So here we go

I assume you already have CGFontRef with you. If not let me know I will tell you how to load a ttf from resource bundle into CgFontRef.

Below is the code snippet to compute the bounds of any string with any CGFontref

```
        int charCount = [string length];
        CGGlyph glyphs[charCount];
        CGRect rects[charCount];

        CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(theCTFont, (const unichar*)[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding], glyphs, charCount);
        CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(theCTFont, kCTFontDefaultOrientation, glyphs, rects, charCount);

        int totalwidth = 0, maxheight = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < charCount; i++)
        {
            totalwidth += rects[i].size.width;
            maxheight = maxheight < rects[i].size.height ? rects[i].size.height : maxheight;
        }

        dim = CGSizeMake(totalwidth, maxheight);
```

Reuse the same function CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters to get the glyphs. To get a CTFontRef from a CGFontRef use CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont() function

Also remember NSFont and CGFontRef are toll-free bridged, meaning they can casted into each other and they will work seamlessly without any extra work.

Comment: But you left out the actual answer... how to actually DRAW that text in the rect... The code in your question uses AppKit (NS) APIs, and your question (and my requirement...) is to draw text over CGBitmapContext, using only CoreGraphics APIs (so to be cross iOS/MacOS). Could you expand just a little?

Answer (score 8):

I would continue with your above approach but use NSAttributedString instead.

```
NSGraphicsContext* newCtx = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:bitmapContext flipped:true];
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:newCtx];
NSAttributedString *string = /* make a string with all of the desired attributes */;
[string drawInRect:locationToDraw];
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
```

Comment: How are NSGraphicsContext and the aligned APIs you use compatible with CGContext and its own APIs ? could these be intermixed? My code is part of cross-platform SDK that should run both iOS MacOS etc, and so I'm limiting myself to CoreGraphics APIs - could you please enhance your answer to work on a CGBitmapContext ?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5 version!**

```
let targetSize: CGSize = // the space you have available for drawing the text
let origin: CGPoint = // where you want to position the top-left corner
let string: String = // your string
let font: UIFont = // your font

let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key:Any] = [.font: font]
let boundingRect = string.boundingRect(with: targetSize, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: attrs, context: nil)
let textRect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: boundingRect.size)
text.draw(with: textRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: attrs, context: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete sample code (Objective-C):

```
//  Need to create pdf Graphics context for Drawing text
    CGContextRef pdfContextRef = NULL;
    CFURLRef writeFileUrl = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:writeFilePath];
    
    if(writeFileUrl != NULL){
        pdfContextRef = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(writeFileUrl, NULL, NULL);
    }
    
//  Start page in PDF context
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContextRef, NULL);
    
    NSGraphicsContext* pdfGraphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithCGContext:pdfContextRef flipped:false];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    
//  Need to set the current graphics context
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:pdfGraphicsContext];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:26], NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    NSAttributedString * currentText=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Write Something" attributes: attributes];

//  [currentText drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 300, 500, 100 )];
    [currentText drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(100, 100)];
    
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

//  Close all the created pdf Contexts
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContextRef);
    CGPDFContextClose(pdfContextRef);
```