# iOS - How can I inlude streetnames in my map?

Tags: ios, dictionary, drawing, openstreetmap

I have a problem with my iOS application. I receive binary vector data from a server (recalculated from osm data) and draw a map from it. Therefore I create polygons, polylines, points and symbols (bitmaps). Of course I also get information like streetnames which I want to include in my map, but how can I make the writing fit into the street? Is there any framework I could use to modify a string on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw your own string on the screen. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386367/drawing-text-with-core-graphics) answer. Or you can read [this](http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2009/06/01/drawing-nsstrings-in-unusual-rotations/) article.